# Informix SQL / insert result of stored procedure in table

Tags: sql, informix

```
kassa_akt_revizii_parser('','','') returns field(per_monets_5,per_monets_10,per_monets_25,per_monets_50,per_rub_1,per_rub_5,per_rub_10,per_rub_25,per_rub_50,per_rub_100,per_rub_200,per_rub_500,per_val_376,per_val_428,per_val_498,per_val_643,per_val_840,per_val_978,per_val_980)
```

We need to do an insert into a table:

```sql
insert into kassa_akt_revizii_pereschet(
id_akt_revizii,per_monets_5,per_monets_10,per_monets_25,per_monets_50,
per_rub_1, per_rub_5, per_rub_10, per_rub_25, per_rub_50,
per_rub_100, per_rub_200, per_rub_500,per_val_376, 
per_val_428, per_val_498, per_val_643, per_val_840,
per_val_978, per_val_980)
values(50, kassa_akt_revizii_parser('','',''));
```

*Number of columns in INSERT does not match number of VALUES*

Comment: `insert into kassa_akt_revizii_pereschet( id_akt_revizii, .......)
    select 50, t.* from kassa_akt_revizii_parser('','','') t`

Comment: A syntax error has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO kassa_akt_revizii_pereschet(
    id_akt_revizii,
    per_monets_5,
    per_monets_10,
    per_monets_25,
    per_monets_50,
    per_rub_1, 
    per_rub_5, 
    per_rub_10, 
    per_rub_25, 
    per_rub_50,
    per_rub_100, 
    per_rub_200, 
    per_rub_500,
    per_val_376, 
    per_val_428, 
    per_val_498, 
    per_val_643, 
    per_val_840,
    per_val_978, 
    per_val_980
)
SELECT 50, *
FROM TABLE(kassa_akt_revizii_parser('','',''));
```

Example:

```
[infx1210@tardis ~]$ dbaccess -e db1 test.sql

Database selected.

CREATE TABLE tab1( col1 INT, COL2 INT, COL3 INT);
Table created.



CREATE FUNCTION sp1() RETURNING INT, INT
        RETURN 1, 2;
END FUNCTION;
Routine created.

;

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (0, sp1());
  236: Number of columns in INSERT does not match number of VALUES.
Error in line 7
Near character position 26


INSERT INTO tab1
SELECT 1, *
FROM TABLE(sp1());
1 row(s) inserted.



SELECT * FROM tab1;

       col1        col2        col3

          1           1           2

1 row(s) retrieved.



Database closed.

[infx1210@tardis ~]$
```

Answer (score 2):

> Number of columns in INSERT does not match number of VALUES

Your error message simply denotes that while insert (columns) does not match number of (values) that you are inserting.

Check them again and insert again .

Insert query :

```
insert into tablename (column1,column2,...column50) values (value1,value2...value50)
```

Comment: how to insert? if it swears on syntax